# Apache rewrite to test directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use apache redirects to change directories between my production and test folders if I use the subdomain `test` like `test.mywebsite.com` but I think it gets stuck in an infinite loop. I am sure it is something simple but I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
<Directory />       
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase   /var/www/mywebsite
    RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}  ^test\.[^.]+\.com$
    RewriteRule   ^(.+) %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
    RewriteRule   (.*) /var/www/mywebsite_dev   
</Directory>
```

EDIT
I am getting errors in the apache log like this.

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
redirected from r->uri = /mywebsite_dev/mywebsite_dev/
redirected from r->uri = /mywebsite_dev/
redirected from r->uri = /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're explicitly checking for the `test` subdomain, then don't use the `RewriteBase`.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^test\. [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^/?mywebsite_dev/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mywebsite_dev/$1 [L]
```

Also, the path specified by a `RewriteRule` is appended after the `www` or `public_html` dir. So, don't provide an absolute system file path there as the resulting final path would be incorrect then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try and received the same type of infinite loop in the logs. I changed the apache log to debug and it looks like it continues to append the /mywebsite_dev over and over until it fails. I have updated my question with the error message and what it is doing. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ravi for the help this did work but I had another question. I was wondering if it is possible to change the directory without rewriting the url? I want test.mywebsite.com to use a different directory but not change the url. It just needs to access files from mywebsite_dev instead of mywebsite. Is this possible or would it just be another virtual host?

Comment: Yes, you would modify your local httpd.conf and add a virtualhost for the test subdomain.